# Adjunta imagen a correo Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Estoy intentando adjunta varias imágenes al cuerpo de un correo, sin embargo cuando el correo llega se muestra la misma imagen en el cuerpo.

Este es el script que estoy usando para recorrer las imágenes del arreglo.

```
foreach ($attachment as $key => $value) {
        $inlineFIle = $this->email->attach( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/'. $value->directorio . $value->nombre_archivo, 'inline');
        $cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($inlineFIle);
        $body .= "<img src='cid:". $cid ."' alt='picture' />";
}
```

Si por ejemplo, quito la línea del body, adjunta todas las imágenes de forma correcta al correo, pero sin mostrarlas dentro del cuerpo del mensaje.

¿Alguna idea?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el error es que estás pasando a la función attachment_cid() el valor de respuesta de la función attach().

La función attach() según la documentación retorna:

Returns:
CI_Email instance (method chaining)

Return type:
CI_Email

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

A la funcion attachment_cid() hay que pasarle el la ruta y nombre de archivo:

```
foreach ($attachment as $key => $value) 
{   
    $archivo = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/'. $value->directorio . $value->nombre_archivo
    $this->email->attach( $archivo, 'inline');
    $cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($archivo);
    $body .= "<img src='cid:". $cid ."' alt='picture' />";
}
```

Espero que te funcione! =)

Comment: Tienes razón, lo apliqué y funciona. ¡Gracias!